# Jquery Sorting table row not working in IE but works in all other browsers

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to sort table rows Asc and Desc when clicking in a column header. It is working fine in firefox and in Chrome but not working in IE. I have tried different things such as getting the latest version of jquery and I still get the same issues. 
Some columns sort alphebetically, some sort by numerical values, some will sort based on null values and finally some sort on checkstate. I am sorting based on classes.

I can not use a plugin. This is what I have. Why does this work in all browsers except in IE? I have looked and looked and I can not find an example like this anywhere where someone is sorting the same way.
Any info would be helpful. Thanks!

Here's the jquery-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.s').click(function () { //this is my header click

        var NotOptional;
        var checkState;

        if ($(this).hasClass('o')) { //optional column
            NotOptional = false;
        } else {
            NotOptional = true;
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('cs')) { //class on my input items
            checkState = true;
        } else {
            checkState = false;
        }


        var o = $(this).hasClass('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        $('.s').removeClass('asc').removeClass('desc');
        $(this).addClass(o);

        var colIndex = $(this).prevAll().length;  //getting the rows
        var tbod = $(this).closest("table").find("tbody")
        var rows = tbod.find("tr").not('.first');

        rows.sort(function (a, b) {

            if (checkState == true) {   //if its a check box or radio
                var A = $(a).find("td input").eq(colIndex);  //getting checkstate
                var B = $(b).find("td input").eq(colIndex);

                if (A.is(':checked') == true) {
                    A = 1;  //setting row value to compare
                } else {
                    A = 0;
                }
                if (B.is(':checked') == true) {
                    B = 1;
                } else {
                    B = 0;
                }

                if (A < B) {  //returning compare for input
                    return A < B;
                } else if (A == B) {
                    return A == B;
                } else if (A > B) {
                    return A > B;
                }

            } else {
                if (NotOptional == false) {  //not optional never blank 
                    var A = $(a).find("td").eq(colIndex).text().toUpperCase();
                    var B = $(b).find("td").eq(colIndex).text().toUpperCase();

                } else { 
//these don't have to have a value but might contain numeric, letter or a null value
                    var A = $(a).find("td").eq(colIndex).text().toUpperCase();
                    var B = $(b).find("td").eq(colIndex).text().toUpperCase();
                    if (!isNaN(A)) A = Number(A);
                    if (!isNaN(B)) B = Number(B);
                }
            }

            return o == 'asc' ? A > B : A < B;
        });

        $.each(rows, function (index, ele) {
            tbod.append(ele); //appending the rows
        });

    }); //end sortable click
```

I am stuck on this and can not figure out why IE doesn't understand the row sorting. If it helps, this jquery is on user control on an aspx page. I have checked the markup using dev tools in IE and the classes are there, It runs through the Jquery click but when it compares the rows it gets all confused and just appends them randomly (ie- Doesn't sort anything)

Comment: Not sure if this will make any difference but you're missing a semi colon at the end of this line : var tbod = $(this).closest("table").find("tbody")

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that. Didn't fix it, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Is there some sort of constraint on IE for class names? I can't help but think maybe IE puts a char limit or MAX num of classes it will except and understand? Some rows will move in IE, but some rows don't move at all.

Comment: Are you gettig any errors in the console? Perhaps making heavy use of console.log function before and after a variable is modified would provide some illumination on what IE actually thinks its dealing with might shed some light?

Comment: Any similarities between rows which do and those which do not move?

Comment: no similarities, sometimes rows move, sometimes they don't. When clicking the header, the rows move around in IE but they don't sort. I have an AltColor for rows so I can see if they move or not. IE also isn't sorting the numerical values at all. 2 is bigger than 1, ha. Firefox and chrome understand..lol. I hate IE, but I have to get this to work. I saw an example where someone returned a 1, -1 or "0" value. The zero value being if the rows were equal and didn't need to move. I tried this method but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I broke down and decided to use Tablesorter. thanks for all the help everyone. I recommend to anyone wanting to sort tables and need cross browser support, Use tablesorter and just write your own Parser.

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-advanced.html